# Boundary lines in Euclid geometry.

Tags: geometry, axiomatic-geometry

I have noted that by many plane geometric proofs or constructions the following propositon is implicitly used:

***Proposition***: Straight line and circle are boundary lines.

where the boundary line is defined as:

***Definition***: A boundary line is a line which divides the plane in two regions in such a way, that any two points situated in the same region can be connected by a line which does not intersect the boundary, whereas any line connecting two points situated in different regions intersects the boundary.

I wonder if the above proposition can be proved on the base of Euclid postulates. After some thoughts I doubt that this is the case. If I am correct can one nevertheless  use the proposition in practical proofs?

Answer (score 1):

Euclid in *[Elements](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/defI15.html)* uses phrases like

> A circle is a plane figure *contained* by one line such that (...) [emphasis added]

which vaguely resembles your idea about a boundary. However in *Elements* we won't find a rigid notion of a *intersection* - the crucial word you had used.

Lack of explicit definition of a *intersection* is a valid objection. We can rise it from the very beginning of *Elements*.

Take Theorem 1 ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6B0x.png)). It states that on a given finite straight line AB it is possible to construct a equilateral triangle ABC by drawing two circles with radius AB, and center in A and B. Then letting C to be a point where circles *intersect*. By drawing AC and BC we constructed equilateral triangle ABC.

But there is no way to make sure that circles will *intersect* using previous statements! Without notion of intersection we can't even construct equilateral triangles on a given line!

Thus in modern euclidean geometry new postulates, which resembles your proposition, are added. Below are two from *The Non-Euclidean Revolution* by Richard J Trudeau.

> Postulate 6. (i) A circle (or triangle) separates the points of the
>   plane not on the circle (triangle) into two regions called its outside
>   and inside ([see Figure 21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlTtM.png)); (ii) any line drawn from a point
>   outside to a point inside intersects the circle (triangle); and (iii)
>   any straight line drawn from a point on the circle (triangle) to a
>   point inside will, if produced indefinitely beyond the point inside,
>   intersect the circle (triangle) exactly one more time.
>
> Postulate 7. (i) A straight line extending infinitely far in both
>   directions separates the points of the plane not on it into two
>   regions called its sides ([see Figure 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgrrd.png)); and
>   (ii) any line drawn
>   from a point on one side to a point on the other side intersects the
>   infinite straight line.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my thoughts and for the mention of the "intersection problem". How is the intersection of two lines defined in modern geometry?

Comment: @user As far as I can tell in Hilbert's plane geometry (and its later modifications) _incidence_ is one of primitive terms describing relation of a _point_ to a _line_.
You might be interested in subchapter _Incidence Geometry_ and Chapter 3. _Hilbert's Axioms_ in Greenberg, M. J. (1973). _Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries: development and history._